# Possible causes for Arch WLAN connection breaking?

Tags: arch-linux, wlan

I have an internet connection that won't stay connected.

My build:

> Arch x86_64 plain UEFI/BIOS install on USB mSATA SSD
>   Network Manager
>   dhcp is enabled at boot with static IP
>   resolv.conf is set to use OpenNIC

I have no problem with booting up and connecting to the internet. However, it will eventually disconnect and I can not reconnect until I reboot. I always get the same timeout failure.

This seems to only occur when I am using a VPN or VirtualBox (E.g.: Windows 7 VM from inside Arch). I can still initally use the VPN or VM internet normally with good settings but it will inevitable disconnect. I don't want to conclude that the VPN or VM are related to the cause but I do notice that it will happen fairly quickly (5 minutes to 1 hour).

I may not fully understand how dhcp, resolv.conf and resolvconf.conf are working in relation to each other.

All generate an identical output before and after the fact:

> ip addr, ip route, iw list, iw mlan0 info

I have added this to create a static IP:

> dhcpcd.conf
>
> # define static profile
>   profile static_mlan0
>   static ip_address=192.168.1.11
>   static routers=192.168.1.1
>   static domain_name_servers=107.170.95.180
>
> # fallback to static profile on mlan0
>   interface mlan0
>   fallback static_mlan0

I added the OpenNic DNS servers to resolv.conf:

> resolv.conf
>
> # Generated by resolvconf
>   nameserver 198.100.146.51
>   nameserver 192.168.1.1
>   nameserver 107.170.95.180
>   nameserver 75.127.14.107

Intersetingly, even with 192.168.1.1 there, I do not have the heartbleed, atleast according to IPLeak.net Oddly, to me, 107.170.95.180 is never at the top of the list even it is written expressly in the dhcpcp.conf. It is using the manual entry from resolvconf.conf.

> resolvconf.conf
>
> name_servers=75.127.14.107
>   name_servers=107.170.95.180
>   name_servers=198.100.146.51

Journaling has been off in fstab since creation per SSD r/w issues.

I have been struggling to understand how I can fix this issue for over a month and a half. Has anyone see any mistakes here or know what could be causing this? Any help would be appreciated.

---

APPENDED
per comment #1

> ping 192.168.1.1
>
> PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   From 192.168.1.11 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
>   From 192.168.1.11 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable

No output from the TCP dump. It is stalled. Not sure what Ethernet is doing here. I don't have any cables connected other than the mSATA USB.

> tcpdump -i mlan0 -n
>
> tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
>   listening on mlan0, link-type EN10MB (**Ethernet**), capture size 262144 bytes

Comment: Can you still ping the gateway? `ping 192.168.1.1` What is the output of `tcpdump -i mlan0 -n` when connectivity has been lost (and you try to ping the gateway)?

Comment: @Hauke Laging - I appended the output for both. It looks strange that Ethernet is there but it also says this before I lose the connection.

Comment: I am not familiar with wireless networking. This problem seems to be the WLAN. It may be useful to change the question title and tags. Does the connection work again if you do this? `ifdown mlan0; ifup mlan0`

Comment: It just crashed 5 minutes ago with only Firefox first time I noticed this. I'll try this next time it crashes. In the meantime, I will update the title and tags. Thanks.

Comment: @Hauke Laging - i tried the ifdown/ifup commands but they don't exist. i've been searching for a reason why i dont have this command/if i should/what are the dependencies/how do i get it questions. But, I havent found anything other than man pages and man style pages on usage. i dont want to seem dependent but i am really stumped. I am not getting responses here, Arch forums or Linux forum. :/

Comment: I guess the reason is that this is a non-trivial problem... You could try `ip link set mlan0 down; ip link set mlan0 up` instead. But I don't know whether that affects the WLAN layer (to tell the truth: I don't know that for `ifdown` either). Maybe it's even a hardware problem.